# How to support multiple updates in this trigger?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update

Below is the code of a trigger, basically it calls a function in case the record that is being updated does not have other row associated by it's Id in another table.
In a multiple row update this trigger fails, how can I edit it to make compatible?

```
declare @slugExists int =(select Id from [dbo].[UrlRecord] 
                              where EntityId = (select Id from inserted) 
                              and EntityName = 'Category')

    if(@slugExists is null) 
    begin
        declare @slug nvarchar (200) = (select Name from inserted)
        EXEC @slug = dbo.GenerarSlug @str= @slug

        insert into [dbo].[UrlRecord] ([EntityId],[EntityName],[Slug],[IsActive],[LanguageId])
        values ( (select Id from inserted) ,'Category',@slug,1,0)
    end
```

EDIT

Based in comments, here is the code of the function GenerarSlug :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GenerarSlug]
(   
    @str VARCHAR(500),
    @modificador VARCHAR(3) = NULL
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @IncorrectCharLoc SMALLINT
SET @str = LOWER(@str)
SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ]%',@str)
WHILE @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
BEGIN
SET @str = STUFF(@str,@incorrectCharLoc,1,'')
SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ]%',@str)
END
SET @str = REPLACE(@str,'  ','')
SET @str = REPLACE(@str,'   ','')
SET @str = REPLACE(@str,' ','-')
IF(@MODIFICADOR IS NOT NULL) SET @str = @str + @MODIFICADOR
RETURN @str
END
```

It transforms 'Especial Chárs' to 'especial-chrs' 
The reason I put this in a function is that it will be called from a few triggers in database so I don't repeat it each time

Comment: What does the procedure `dbo.GenerarSlug`, I suspect the most efficient solution is going to be to expand the logic contained within this out to a set based approach in the trigger. Cursors in triggers will kill your database performance.

Comment: It creates a url safe string from a normal string. Please explain your comment "set based approach" a little. I don´t like cursors too much but if there is not another solution I would use it

Comment: Can you post the code for your procedure? Without this it is impossible to suggest an improvement. I expect even with a single inserted value this code is not doing what you think. `EXEC @slug = dbo.GenerarSlug @str= @slug` will set `@slug` to the return value if the procedure, which has to be an integer (usually used for providing the status of the procedure execution).

Comment: @GarethD It is a function, not a procedure. The `EXEC` looks weird, but it is correct (try it!). Msam85, you really do need to post the function code to get a good answer here. "set based" = processing the whole set at once, rather than row-by-row in a cursor or loop.

Comment: @PaulWhite Every day is a school day! That's why I love stackexchange. In all my years of SQL Server experience I have never seen a function called this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dbo.Generarslug` is a scalar function, then you could use the following:

```
INSERT[dbo].[UrlRecord] ([EntityId],[EntityName],[Slug],[IsActive],[LanguageId])
SELECT  i.id,
        'Category', 
        dbo.GenerarSlug(i.Name),
        1,
        0
FROM    inserted AS i
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    [dbo].[UrlRecord] AS r
            WHERE   r.EntityID = i.ID
            AND     r.EntityName = 'Category'
        );
```

There is still potentially scope for improvement depending on what `dbo.GenerarSlug` actually does.